MPU6050 measuring tilt angle while moving
I am working on a project, where the final device will be mounted on a vehicle (horizontally levelled with the vehicle chasis). One important need here is that I need to find out if the device is installed properly in a vehicle. The "proper installation" has many parameters and one of them is the angle of installation. The device must be placed as much as horizontally possible. If the device is installed where the inclination angle goes over a threshold value, it should generate an alert.
I have been playing with MPU6050 and till now I can measure the inclination angle well with the help of G force on X, Y and Z axis.
But as I can understand, when the vehicle will be moving, there will be a force due to acceleration of vehicle (A vehicle never moves with a constant speed in practical). Now this force may be applied either on x axis fully (if installed almost horizontally aligned with vehicle) or on x and z axis if the installation is not proper (for example, the device is attached on vehicle vertically).
Now when the vehicle is not on move, I can calculation the angle the device (the PCB) is inclined to, but how shall I do it when the vehicle is in move and there is external force along with gravity?
Any reference to any article, mathematical solution or code samples will be helpful.

Einstein's 1907 equivalence principle tells us that acceleration is indistinguishable from gravity so there may be limits unless you can get information on the motion through some other means.

True. Any other sensor you can refer that can measure a title angle (perfection is not needed here) without gravity?

Please, specify your goal precisely. Do you want to "find out if the device is installed properly in a vehicle", which can be done when vehicle is not moving, or do you want to find orientation of the vehicle itself, while on the move? "as much as horizontally possible" has no meaning in engineering. Furthermore, it is not absolutely necessary for AHRS systems if correct calibration procedure implemented.

Hi @Maple , I don't need to measure the vehicle's title angle, I need to measure, if the device is tilted (inside vehicle) or not.. By this time, I do understand that probably I'll have to do it while the vehicle is in stationary condition and there is no other cheaper way to do it while the vehicle is moving.

This is exactly where Fusion algorithms, such as Kalman Filter come into play. Nobody uses accelerometers to measure the orientation. Gyroscopes are used for that, because they do not depend on linear acceleration. However they tend to accumulate an error over time, so absolute accelerometer data is fused into relative gyroscope changes to correct these errors.
More advanced systems can provide yaw direction by fusing magnetometer with gyroscope. Even more advanced algorithms can use all 9 DOF for more precision. Expensive AHRS modules use all that plus barometer and GPS but the software becomes quite complicated at that point, unless you can find suitable open source.
This particular device MPU6050 has built-in DMP (digital motion processor) that can do fusion for you and return ready to use quaternions. Working with it can be tricky, but a lot of information is available in the datasheet and on the web.
Alternatively do the search for "sensor fusion" and "Kalman filter" and you will get hundreds of videos and texts explaining how to do this yourself.
Finally, you do not have to mount the sensor with extremely fine precision. All you have to do is add calibration support to you software and preserve initial offsets measured in the stationary position to subtract them from all the readings later. Note that this is always a good code to have due to manufacturing differences and thermal drifts.
UPDATE
If you only concerned with correct device installation then sure there are much easier ways to do this. For example mechanical design of the mounting hardware that uses specific corners/surfaces to ensure correct position.
Furthermore, any IMU-based design is useless unless you can guarantee that a vehicle is perfectly horizontal during installation. This excludes any driving conditions and is pretty much undefined even stationary. A simple change of tire pressure can affect the position of the vehicle a lot, regardless of how level the surface is.
I believe this is a typical case of XY problem.

Gyro won't work here as it is not a continuous motion. Gyro can only measure degree / second. So once the device is fixed with the vehicle frame there won't be any angular movement.

Won't the device move with the vehicle? And isn't vehicle orientation is what you want to find out? At least that is how it works for everybody else.
